# JDOQL regex support

Tags: jdo, jdoql

Does JDOQL support ^ for matching the start and $ for matching the end? I am having troubles getting them to work.

Are ^ and $ maybe already implied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String.matches() support is well defined in the spec

> only the following regular expression patterns are required to be
>   supported and are portable: global “(?i)” for case-insensitive
>   matches; and “.” and “.*” for wild card matches. The pattern passed to
>   matches must be a literal or parameter.